# Updating attached image of news item does not purge scaled image from varnish but only the news item view

Tags: plone, varnish, linguaplone, plone-4.x

Whenever a user replaces/updates the image attached to a news item, then the news item view and folder listing above is purged (updated) on the varnish cache – but the attached image itself is not.

How can I make plone.app.caching to also purge/update not only `<mysite>/news/` and `<mysite>/news/news-item/` but also the images under `<mysite>/news/news-item/image_news_scale` and `<mysite>/news/news-item/image_even_smaller_news_scale`?

Background: Using Plone 4.3.2 I setup my a own custom image scales, e.g. `news_scale` via `<mysite>/@@imaging-controlpanel`. This scale is used for displaying the attached images in news items, e.g. as `<mysite>/news/news-item/image_news_scale`. Moreover, I also have another custom image scale like `even_smaller_news_scale` to be used in folder listings, e.g. as `<mysite>/news/news-item/image_even_smaller_news_scale`. I created these views via `<mysite>/portal_skins/custom` and registered them as default views under `<mysite>/portal_types/` and `select_default_view` action.

PS I just saw now, because I am using [raptus.multilanguageplone](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/raptus.multilanguageplone), the images' URL are available even under a more complicated URL that is dependent upon selected language: `<mysite>/news/news-item/image___de____news_scale` and `<mysite>/news/news-item/image___de____even_smaller_news_scale` (`de` could also be `en` depending on language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you already configured cache purging in plone.app.caching correctly you'll notice that newsitem/image_thumb and other image sizes will get purged correctly by default.

plone.app.caching does not know about the custom urls for the images because of raptus.linguaplone.
so you'll have to create your own adapter that implements `IPurgePaths` for your newsitems

something like this should do the trick:

```
from z3c.caching.interfaces import IPurgePaths


class ItemImagePurgePaths(object):
    """additional paths to purge not covered by 
    plone.app.caching default adapters i.e. ObjectFieldPurgePaths
    """
    implements(IPurgePaths)
    adapts(IYourConentType)

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context

    def getRelativePaths(self):
        prefix = self.context.absolute_url_path()

        return [prefix + '/image____de____news_scale',
                prefix + '/image____de____even_smaller_scale']

    def getAbsolutePaths(self):
        return []
```

see also https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.cachepurging